# SwiftUI uneven scrolling

Tags: swiftui

When scrolling, the columns shift for some reason. How to make a uniform scroll of all columns? Is this a bug in SwiftUI or am I doing something wrong? Please tell me how to fix it.

```
struct GridHStack: View {
    private let users = ["Olya", "Masha", "Dasha", "Katya", "Ivan", "Egor"]
    
    private let hours = 0..<24
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: false, content: {
            LazyHStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders, content: {
                Section(header: Column(), content: {
                    ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                        LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders, content: {
                            Section(header: Box(text: user), content: {
                                ForEach(hours) { h in
                                    Box(text: "x", color: Color.green)
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
    
    func Box(text: String, color: Color? = .blue) -> some View {
        return Text(text)
            .frame(width: 90, height: 60)
            .background(color)
    }
    
    func Column() -> some View {
        return LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders, content: {
            Section(header: Box(text: ""), content: {
                ForEach(hours) { h in
                    Box(text: "\(h):00")
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `.fixedSize` to views that you don't want constantly resized from the child views. Or, if it makes sense for the content and use case, set  `.frame` size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no change. Most likely the matter is in the displacement along the Y axis with a sharp scroll

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean now. It's likely because the cells being produced lazily. This might be a case where you need to use a regular HStack for the columns at least and separate views for the pinned sections.

Comment: @AleksandrPetrov Did you find the solution to this? I'm having the same problem with my scrollview that contains lazyhstacks inside lazyvstacks, tried everything I could, but no luck :(